# Specific compare/equals for List.contains(obj)

Tags: java, collections, equals, contains

Hi@all and thx in advance,

i currently wondering if there is a great best practice for my situation.

- Consider u have an object. Let's say an object of type Customer.
- Within a Customer object u have (n-1) fields.
- Now u are implementing the hashCode and equals method via eclipse context menu >> Sources >> Generate hashCode() and equals()...
  It uses all (n-1) fields to do so. Which is actually not really a bad in the general case.

Additional in a seperate service class within a specific method u have a list of Customers >> List myCustomers.

In this method u implement an if-else case with the condition myCustomers.contains(specificCustomer).

```
if (myCustomer.contains(specificCustomer)) {
   // todo
} else {
   // todo
}
```

So the list.contains(obj) uses internally the equals method of the object. This is the general way to check if a list contains an object.

BUT
In my case i've the standard hashCode and equals allready implemented with all (n-1) fields. And what i want, is to use a/the .contains(obj) method, which checks only specific fields of the object, for example (n-5) fields.

I don't want to adapt the existing hashCode and equals, because other parts of the code allready using this. And if i do so, i can not predict the behavior afterwards.

Also i don't want to write a seperate method within the Customer class and use it only in the if-else-condition.

So, does anyone has an idea, best practice or great pattern to get this done?

Comment: try not to search for best practices, they are often opinion based

Comment: my opinion based solution: create method equalsXXX that uses N-5 fields, create a method that iterates a list and uses equalsXXX method to check equality

Answer (score 0):

You want a specific piece of business logic (the n-5 field equals) to be used so you will have to wrte a specific piece of code somewhere. The simplest which comes to mind is to replace the standard `contains` call with a custom method which iterates over the list and checks if there is an item which matches using the custom equals logic. If you need this version of equals in more places you could extract it into a separate utility or service class.